# Recording from microphone to .wav (or other) under DJGPP

Tags: c++, audio, microphone, djgpp

I'm hoping to programmatically record several sound files from a microphone under DOS using DJGPP.

So far my research has pointed to OpenAL, but I can't find anything definite that that's the best way to go. I'm wondering if anyone here's done this before and can save me some time?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OpenAL implementation for DOS. Why do you want to do it under DOS? Anyway, look for original SoundBlaster API.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I _have_ to do this under DOS unfortunately, so I'm stuck with it. Care to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @Galwegian: Well, there is Sound Blaster SDK for DOS available. It should support playing/recording waveform and MIDI. But remember it's almost 20 years old and uses really low level (ISA DMA).

Answer (score 0):

did you take a look to [allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) ? It has some sound recording features : http://alleg.sourceforge.net/latestdocs/en/alleg029.html and it is working with [DJGPP](http://www.allegro.cc/docs/dos-djgpp-compile.html)